# Simple VB 2010 application not saving data to Access 2007

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, ms-access-2007

I've downloaded the trial version of VB 2010 and made a small application that connects to an Access 2007 MDB file.

A couple of things are going wrong:

1. If I try to publish it, and then run the setup file generated, it says it can't find the .MDB file.
2. If I run it during development (F5), it runs fine, and when I enter new data into a DataGridView, I know it gets saved because when I close the session and hit F5 again, the newly entered data is still present. (The relevant code for updating the data is simple enough):

   ```
   Me.Validate()
   Me.MenuItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
   Me.MenuItemsTableAdapter.Update(Me.MenuOrdersDataSet.MenuItems)
   Me.MenuOrdersDataSet.AcceptChanges()
   ```

But if I close the whole project and rerun it and view the DataGridView, or if I manually go and check out the .MDB file, it no longer has the newly entered data.

This is my connection code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.MenuItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MenuOrdersDataSet.MenuItems)
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbString As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

    dbString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MenuOrders.accdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbString
    con.Open()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "MenuItems")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

What's the matter? Are these problems related to having a trial version, or are there some other obvious problems I should be aware of?

Comment: What is your connection string used to reach the database? This is the database that gets the updates when you run the program. But you should be carefull to not overwrite with a fresh copy every time you start your program.

Comment: I've edited my question to add the connection string, in fact the whole formload code. I copied this connection string from what Visual Studio gave me when I added the data source.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem, and I think I fixed it by setting my data source/ database **Copy to Output Directory** to "Copy if newer", located in the properties window for the MyDatabase.mdf file.

Sometimes the option can default to "Always" which explains why the data set *resets* every time you run the application.

Comment: I tried this. In the Properties window of MenuOrders.accdb I changed it from Copy Always to Copy if Newer, but no difference. When I open the .MDB database itself, the changes have not been saved there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally did the following to fix it.

In Solution Explorer I opened App.config and put the absolute path to the database in the `connectionStrings` tag, replacing the default `|DataDirectory|` text.

Not sure if this is the best thing to do..but it worked!

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MenuSystem.My.MySettings.MenuDBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MenuDB.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```